Where in the azure portal can I return to my custom model?
I have created a custom form recognizer model in Document Intelligence Studio.  When I returned later I see no way to select my project.  I have to select one of the "sample" links of Getting started after going into Document Intelligence Studio.  So, the only path back into my model I can see is "Go to Document Intelligence Studio", but once there I see no reference on where to get back into my project.  What am I missing?

So you are saying when you go to Document Intelligence Studio,
select the Custom extraction models tab, you are not seeing your custom model which you created?

No, but rather when I first select Doc Intelligence Studio.... I only see various categories of models, eg.  prebuilt, custom etc.  I would expect to see a list of my projects Ive already started.  Its only by accident that I selected "custom models" that I was able to find my project again.  Seems like there should be a link somewhere like there is to other Azure resource types?
